# remove � this symbol from the string in php

Tags: php, string

I have an issue with insert and update query while detecting  � this symbol in data.
so i want to remove  � this symbol from the string and replace with '''  eg: 'dickey�s-barbecue-pit-d'iberville'.

thanks,

Comment: need some more explanation of your question, and from where you get this value?

Comment: @HirenMangukiya Actually that string from database.result of a select query .query returns name and city.then i .concatenated string of name and city.and some data from db contain diamond symbol so updating of field name 'permalink' with the above string failed.

Comment: � is a replacement character. Replacement is one technique of handling corrupt text. Text corruption like that can occur when reading text bytes with an encoding other than the encoding it was written with. That would be a bug. See if you can find such a bug and fix it. If you can't, consider that the users might very well want to know that their text is corrupted so removing it would be doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 1):

I think that symbol is a Unicode character 
So you can remove these types of characters by

```
 $str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]/u','',$string);
```

This just removes 0-31 and 127. This works in ASCII and UTF-8 because both share the same control set range (as noted by mgutt below). Strictly speaking, this would work without the /u modifier. But it makes life easier if you want to remove other chars

Comment: @Trishna Please check the edited code. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you.

```
$string = "dickey�s-barbecue-pit-d'iberville";

$new = preg_replace('/[^x00-x7f]/', '', $string);

echo $new;
```

Comment: I tried the above code.but that will replace all special characters.i need all other characters except that diamond sign.because i want to set that string as a permalink.

Answer (score 0):

You may copy same character and use it:

[**PHPfiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/982d-kiap) - Hit Run or F9

```
$str = "dickey�s-barbecue-pit-d'iberville";
$str = str_replace('�', "'", $str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I got the solution as,

```
$final = utf8_encode($string);
```

here, `$string` = dickey�s-barbecue-pit-flowood;

and   **`$final` = dickeys-barbecue-pit-flowood;**

Thanks,

Comment: it displays **`dickeyï¿½s-barbecue-pit-d'iberville`** on my local server as well as on this [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ruas-1uqg)